# Level configuration Java Logging API by properties file

Tags: logging, java.util.logging

i have trouble using the java logging api. My error seems to be pretty basic but i can't find it.
I use the following configuration file :

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL

.level= FINEST
com = SEVERE
```

But it seems that only the .level-parameter is used. When i log from a logger called "com.test" (`private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.test");`) the log shows all levels and ignores that the com package is SEVERE.
When i change the .level parameter everything works as expected and therefore i'm sure to use the right configurationfile.

All documentation that i have seen shows that this should work. Anyone sees my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:
    com.level = SEVERE

Now i feel really stupid ...

Comment: Don't be so hard with you. I lost half a day of work on the same problem... You save my day :-)